# NSHTTPCookie saving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm using `ASIFormDataRequest` and getting cookies in response. I'm trying to save them into `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
NSArray * requestCookies = request.responseCookies;
NSArray * requestCookies = request.responseCookies;
if (requestCookies.count) {
    NSData *cookiesData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:requestCookies];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cookiesData forKey:kCookies_Key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Request cookies: %@", requestCookies);
}
/* output:
Request cookies: (
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"name1\" value:\"value1\" expiresDate:(null)
created:2013-02-27 17:49:27 +0000 (3.8368e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE 
domain:\"www.example.com\" path:\"/path\" isSecure:FALSE>",
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"name2\" value:\"value2\" expiresDate:(null)
created:2013-02-27 17:49:27 +0000 (3.8368e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE 
domain:\"www.example.com\" path:\"/path\" isSecure:FALSE>"*/
```

And then I'm trying to restore this cookies:

```
NSData *cookiesData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCookies_Key];
if ([cookiesData length]) {
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookiesData];
    NSLog(@"Restored cookies: %@", cookies);
}
/* output:
Restored cookies: (
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"name1\" value:\"value1\" expiresDate:(null)
created:2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 (1) sessionOnly:TRUE 
domain:\"www.example.com\" path:\"/path\" isSecure:FALSE>",
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"name2\" value:\"value2\" expiresDate:(null)
created:2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 (1) sessionOnly:TRUE 
domain:\"www.example.com\" path:\"/path\" isSecure:FALSE>"*/
```

Only difference between this cookies: creation date. Probably I will save only properties of this two cookies in `NSUserDefaults`, but  why I'm having different cookie creation dates?

**UPD**

I've tried to save only properties of `NSHTTPCookie` and create this cookie again, but I'm having same creation date:

```
created:2001-01-01 00:00:01 +0000 (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather save them on the SharedCookie storage space:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]
```